# Click away from tkinter.Enrry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I programmed a simple game, where you run around and collect symbols for points against an other player. Under the Canvas I have 2 entries, where each player can write his name, and it'll be showed too. My only problem is that you can't click away from the entry. One player moves his character with the WASD keys and its frustrating, that everything he does is written in the entry box. Is there a way to click away from there?

Comment: Why not inputting the players' name first before starting the game?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is how to move the keyboard focus. You do that with the `focus_set` method which is available on every widget. For example, to move the focus away from the entry and into a canvas you could do something like this:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
...
canvas.focus_set()
```